# how to show border of clicked div only?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a help in this jquery or javascript problem. I have many divs with some particular ids and onclick that div the border should get changed and onclick another div with different id the border of that div again get changed like previous div but border of previous div get removed.

Comment: Please post code samples of your efforts thus far. It will make it easier for people to help you. :)

Comment: Please, upload the code you've written so far so we can help you debug it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
.mydiv {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:yellow;
  float:left;
  margin:10px;
}
.active{
  border: 10px solid black;
}
</style>

<div class="mydiv">A</div>
<div class="mydiv">B</div>
<div class="mydiv">C</div>

<script>
  $(".mydiv").click(function(){

    $(".mydiv").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

  });
</script>
```

Comment: I took your idea, and stripped the irrelevant parts away so that the focus lies more on the solution part :) I also changed it to a class instead of hardcoding some styling, but the principle remains.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the snippet below to see my attempt. What it does is once you click on a div with the class `clickable` the code removes the `border` class from the previous div, adds the `border` class to the newly clicked div and updates the `prevDiv`.

I prefer this method because where other people use `$('div').css('border', 'none');` to remove all the borders from every div, this code only removes the border from the previously clicked div. Thus allowing you to have (non `clickable`) divs with a predefined border/`border` class.

```js
let prevDiv;

$(".clickable").click(function(){
  $(prevDiv).removeClass('border');
  $(this).addClass('border');
  
  prevDiv = $(this);
});
```

```css
.clickable {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.border {
  border: 5px solid black;
}

#firstID {
  background-color: red;
}

#secondID {
  background-color: orange;
}

#thirdID {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="clickable" id="firstID">Placeholder text</div>
<div class="clickable" id="secondID">Placeholder text</div>
<div class="clickable" id="thirdID">Placeholder text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
// The class div class is the div tag if you want and Id replace
// Replace the . with a #
$(".the_div_class").click(()=>{
  $(".the_div_class").addClass("the_border_class");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi. This doesnt answer the question, what if you have multiple `.the_div_class` and you click one, and then another? The first one shiould turn off :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".mydiv").click(function(){

$(this).css('border','10px solid black');

});
```

```css
.mydiv
{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="mydiv">ABCD</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi. This doesnt answer the question, what if you have multiple .the_div_class and you click one, and then another? The first one shiould turn off :)

Comment: Also, You now have two ansers to the same question. Please update one (I suggest adding an example to the other post as it's more future-proof) and delete the other.

Answer (score 0):

you can write in **java script** -

```
let yourDivIds =["your_div1","your_div2"];  // specify all your div ids

function removeGlowingDivs() { // this will remove class from other div's
    yourDivIds.forEach(item=>{
        document.getElementById(divID).removeClass('your_class_name');
    })
}

// add this on click event on all div's
function highlightDiv(divID) { // this will add class

    removeGlowingDivs();
    document.getElementById(divID).addClass('your_class_name');
}
```

Comment: It's preferred on SO that you explain what you've done. That is javascript is obvious, as it's a JS question. It would be more helpfull if you described *what* you did and *why* you did that :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
    $('div').click(function(){
       $('div').css('border', 'none');
       $(this).css('border', '1px solid black');
    });
```

NOTE: Replace the `$(div)` with the relevant parent element's ID or class.

Comment: It's preferred on SO that you explain what you've done. That is javascript is obvious, as it's a JS question. It would be more helpfull if you described *what* you did and *why* you did that :)